# How do I retrieve variables from an OPTIONAL statement in SPARQL?

Tags: sparql

If I give my SPARQL query a known item which could be a number of different types. Depending on which type I'm currently interested in I want to get a certain property from this type (the way to do this will be different for each type) but once I have found this property I want to perform the same operation.

currently I have the following pseudocode:

```
?object rdf:hasProperty "known Property Type"
OPTIONAL {
?object rdf:hasProperty "property type 1"
#do this thing and store thing of interest in ?variableOfInterest
}
OPTIONAL{
?object rdf:hasProperty "property type 2"
#do different thing and store thing of interest in ?variableOfInterest
}
?thingIAmActuallyInterestedIn rdf:has type ?variableOfInterest
#now do long query
```

My problem is that outside of the OPTIONAL statement `?variableOfInterest` does not get passed out, instead `?thingIAmActuallyInterestedIn` is just a list off all objects.

I could put the 'long query' in both of the optional blocks but that would be a huge amount of code replication.

Is there a way to output the `?variableOfInterest` from the optional statement rather than it being a dummy variable?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that `?variableOfInterest` is in the `SELECT` clause, or it's `*`

`?variableOfInterest` will be bound in result rows when the `OPTIONAL` matched, and unbound when the `OPTIONAL` did not match.

How that gets reflected to your code depends on the API of your SPARQL engine.